# How can I get my bookmarks shown in nemo quicklists automatically

Tags: nautilus, quicklists, nemo

How can I get my bookmarks, shown in Nemo Quicklists automatically.

Like nautilus can right now. As seen in the image below.

[image: nautilus-quiclist]

When i create a bookmark in nautilus, it is automatically shown in Nautilus Quick-lists.

How can i get that exact same feature for nemo!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves, as of `2.0.8` nemo is able to show bookmarks from `quicklist`, so the answer to the question is, update to the latest `nemo`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~shiba89/+archive/nemo-unity) is working on it, however the description says not to use it because it's a work in progress, but it's at least worth watching to see how far it gets. <del>If anyone else knows of another way, like a way to manually create quicklists for it, please do tell.</del>

**UPDATE:** I found a solution, it's not "automatic" so to speak, but I found a way to manually and *easily* add quicklists for bookmarks and places. Menulibre supports creating Unity quicklists.

To install Menulibre first open a terminal, `Ctrl+Alt+T`, then enter the following commands:
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:menulibre-dev/devel`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install menulibre`

Now when you launch Menulibre, look for the Nemo launcher (it'll be titled 'Home Folder', so doing a search for 'nemo' will not work), you'll notice when editing a launcher in Menulibre there's a tab for 'Quicklists', click on it and add your items. For the commands, here's an example, to make a quicklist for 'Documents' just type `nemo Documents`, the working directory for the commands is your home directory, so just typing the name of the folder after 'nemo' is enough.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I once wrote a tutorial(http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/quicklists-for-unity.html) on how to do it manually. but i don't know how they do it automatically.